# Rendering bottle/liquid

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lines

I am fairly new to Blender and am only using it to create a mockup of a bottle and label for a university project.
Now I followed a lot of tutorials and am done with my bottle, yet when I render it, the result turns out to be not only very low quality and pixelated, but the liquid inside the bottle shows these weird lines. I used modifiers to smooth everything out but it still shows up like this ..

Does anyone know some kind of solution?
Thanks in advance!

[image: Liquid shading settings]

[image: Render settings]

[image: render result]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stackexchange :) It's hard to say what exactly is going wrong. Could you upload your .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com so people can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

When surfaces overlap, it causes glitchy results in cycles. Make sure there's an air gap between the back of the glass and the liquid inside